# EMR Spark Job Keep running

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a Spark script that I am trying to execute via EMR. My scripts works fine on EMR and completes successfully in 4 minutes but some times the same script with no change keeps on running for hours and I manually have to terminate the EMR cluster, run again and it succeeds without making any change at all. I am unable to figure out the reason for this and need some leads in this direction. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide master node logs.

Comment: @YuriR, can you please let me know how to get those out of EMR please? Thanks!